# I am reading in an excel file with python and I am trying to export it out but it adds a column

Tags: python, excel, windows, pandas

Ok so I am trying to import a spreadsheet in excel and export it out after its been formatted. I already formatted it. The format is repositioning columns ok. So when i export it for whatever reason it adds a column A with an empty title that numbers each row. Please help fix my code so that it does not print this first column. Yes I have done research I tried using "df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1)", It doesn't work.

```
df = pd.read_excel('demo1.xls')
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
df = df[cols] 
df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1)
df.to_excel('demo.xlsx')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iis2Z.jpg)

Comment: Try `df.to_excel('demo.xlsx', index=False)`

Comment: thanks so much couldnt find  this anywhere maybe i just wasnt searching correctly but thanks peter and jan that helped alot

Answer (score 1):

The extra column you are seeing is most probably the index column. The to_excel method allows you to drop this column when exporting to Excel. See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

You want to do this to get rid of the index column:

```
...
df.to_excel('demo.xlsx', index=False)
```